# convert ImageView to Drawable for canvas

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, drawable, android-canvas

I have an ImageView created programmatically. I want to get the entire imageView as a drawable. When I do as follows, I get null back

```
private Drawable getDrawable(Data data) {
    ImageView image = new ImageView(context);
    image.setBackground(data.getColor());
    image.setImageDrawable(data.getIcon());
    return image.getDrawable();
}
```

Now, I also suspect that my method would only return the drawable portion of the imageView, without the background.

How do I get the entire ImageView as a drawable?

**UPDATE:**

The following still does not work:

```
private Drawable getDrawable(Data data) {
    ImageView image = new ImageView(context);
    image.setBackground(data.getColor());
    image.setImageDrawable(data.getIcon());
    image.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    image.buildDrawingCache();
    Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), image.getDrawingCache());
    image.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    return drawable;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before calling `image.buildDrawingCache()` you need to measure and layout the image. You might try following code.

```
int ws = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(imageWidth, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
int hs = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(imageHeight, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
image.measure(ws, hs);
image.layout(0, 0, image.getMeasuredWidth(), image.getMeasuredHeight());
```

Comment: I try your suggestion and for `ws :: hs` I get `1073741824 :: 1073741824`. These numbers are outrageous, are they not? Especially, this is an imageView that my app actually uses elsewhere in the app, and it displays fine as an imageView. But here, I need it to be a drawable.

Comment: Method measure() uses a MeasureSpec, not the size. That's why the numbers. They are ok. ImageWidth and imageHeight are the sizes of your image. You can take them from your icon instance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure this works but I haven't tested it myself. Try using `image.getDrawingCache()` to get a `Bitmap` of the what the `View` is rendered as. You may need to enable draw caching by using `image.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true)`. From there, you can use a `BitmapDrawable` to convert the `Bitmap` into a `Drawable` type. Here is some info from the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getDrawingCache%28%29) on draw cache. And [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html) is some info on `BitmapDrawable`.

Comment: Interesting, do know what isn't working? Is it that the `Bitmap` that is returned is `null` or empty?

Comment: I think it's empty. I know it's not null.

Comment: Another thing I suspect is that the `ImageView` may not have been rendered or drawn yet. If you're calling this method in the `onCreate` method of an `Activity` the `View` hasn't actually been rendered yet. You have to do this on post-layout. I don't know off the top of the my head, but there are ways to execute code after stuff has been laid out.